# Can not put firestore data into flutter list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried to put my firestore data which is scrapped image links into flutter list (var imageList). However, there is a 'RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0' and not worked.

Printed imageList shows like list in list [['link1.jpg','link2.jpg2',link3.jpg3',......]]

My firestore data is one field and several values please, check bellow captured image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLZF.jpg

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

class ProfileController extends GetxController {
  List imageList = [];

  getData() async {
    try {
      var imgJson = await firestore.collection('insta-scrap1').get();

      for (var doc in imgJson.docs) {
        imageList.add(doc['data']);
      }

      print(imageList); }
```

Comment: Actually in your screenshot the data looks like string because the array is qouted inside "[]" is that array declaration??

Answer (score 0):

use `doc.data()` instead of `doc['data']`

```
for (var doc in imgJson.docs) {
   imageList.add(doc.data()['data']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I regret to say I would like to set imageList as 'link1.jpg','link2.jpg2',link3.jpg3',......]. I changed my code to your answer. The result is [{data: 'link1.jpg','link2.jpg2',link3.jpg3',......] which I can not use list shuffle method for next step.

Comment: I changed my code, try and let me know

Comment: I regret to say I've got same print result. So, I changed my code as bellows and get print result is ['link1.jpg','link2.jpg2',link3.jpg3',......]. However, there is same RangeError again and still I do not understand the reason why. Here is my new code as bellows; 
getData() async {
    try {
      var imgJson = await firestore.collection('insta-scrap1').doc('docu1').get();

      imageList = jsonDecode(imgJson['data'].toString());
      print(imageList);
    }